# App armor policy prevents flutter snap from working

Tags: linux, flutter

I am building a snap version of [my opensource flutter app](https://github.com/Robert3141/Connectron).
Everything works fine after running `snap install connectron` to get th release off the snapstore.

Running `connectron` returns

```
Gtk-Message: 12:19:46.398: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.693" (uid=1000 pid=74052 comm="/snap/connectron/3/bin/Connectron " label="snap.connectron.connectron (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="RequestName" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
```

This is on my pretty fresh installation of Pop!OS.

Under further digging I can easily execute the program by changing directory to the bin and executing it:

```
robert@pop-os:~$ cd /snap/connectron/3/bin
robert@pop-os:/snap/connectron/3/bin$ ./Connectron
```

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/failed-to-register-gdbus-error-org-freedesktop-dbus-error-accessdenied/20370/2

Suppose you have an app called `sasomtam`, then you should add this:

```
slots:
  dbus-sasomtam:
    interface: dbus
    bus: session
    name: com.shanuy.sasomtam

apps:
  sasomtam:
    ... # the rest of your app definition
    slots:
      - dbus-sasomtam
```